# Function to transform polynomial to linear

Tags: transformation

It's been a long while since my school days and linear algebra.  I'd like to find the function, if one exists, that transforms $$y = 2x^2 - 1$$ to $$y = x.$$  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\sqrt{y+1\over2}$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=2x^2-1$. You are looking for the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) function of $f$, denoted as $f^{-1}$, that satisfies $$f^{-1}(f(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x.$$

To find it, we just need to represent the input $x$ in terms of the output $y$:
$$
\begin{align}
y&=2x^2-1 \\
2x^2&=y+1 \\
x&=\sqrt \frac{y+1}{2}.
\end{align}
$$
The inverse is therefore
$$
f^{-1}(y)=\sqrt \frac{y+1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Thanks, all.  @Scene answered my question for those particular functions.  More generally, if I might, I'm looking for h(f) to transform quadratic f(x) to linear g(x).  Say, for example, f(x) = 2(x^2) - 1 and g(x) = 3x + 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question. Fwiw, for each real number $y>-1,$ there are two real numbers $x$ such that this $y$ is equal to $2x^2-1:$ $x=\sqrt{y+1\over2}$ and $x=-\sqrt{y+1\over2}.$